# Programmatically Get Custom Lists (User Defined) Only

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, object-model

Is it possible to get the user defined lists (custom lists) in SharePoint 2013 object model? I am not referring to the lists created along with the site definition.

Comment: Actually "custom lists" and "not from site definition" are different sets of lists. The code in my answer will show only *custom* lists, while omitting for example any usual *document libraries* that were created manually. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx :

> Microsoft Corporation products that are built on SharePoint
>   Foundation, such as Microsoft SharePoint Server, can and do define
>   additional list types. Also, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation farms
>   where your solution is deployed may have custom list types created,
>   for example, by adding a CAML ListTemplate Element (List Template) to
>   a Feature or to the ONET.xml file of a custom site definition
>   configuration. (Such **custom list types should have ID values above
>   10000** to ensure that they do not conflict with numbers that will be
>   used by Microsoft in future versions of SharePoint Foundation

Please test this powershell to see if it's what you're looking for:

```
$w = (Get-SPSite $url).OpenWeb()
$w.Lists | select Title,BaseTemplate | where {$_.BaseTemplate -gt 10000}
```

This can be easily rewritten in object model code with `foreach` or Linq